# Error handling for wpdb error - displaying an error message to the user

Tags: javascript, forms, errors, wp-error

I want to display an error message to a user when a php POST form fails. The form lets a user create a new team on my site. If the team name is not unique, the query fails. I want to display a generic error message when this happens.

Here is my form:

```
        <form method="post" id="create_team" action="">
            <p class="form">
                <label for="team_name"><?php _e('Team Name:', 'profile'); ?></label>
                <input class="text-input" name="team_name" type="text" id="team_name" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'team_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>" />
            </p>

            <p class="form">
                <select name="team_type" id="team_type" class="styled-select">
                    <option value="" selected disabled >Team Type</option>
                    <option value="School">School</option>
                    <option value="Neighborhood">Neighborhood</option>
                    <option value="Organization">Organization</option>
                </select>
              </p>
            <p class="form-submit" id="create-team-submit">
                <input name="create_team" type="submit" id="create_team" class="submit button" value= "submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
```

Here is the handler in functions.php:

```
function mytheme_insert_new_team() {

      $name  = $_POST['team_name'];
      $type  = $_POST['team_type'];
      global $wpdb;
      $table_name = "wp_teams";

      $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
                                'team_name' => $name,
                                'team_type' => $type
                                ),array(
                                '%s',
                                '%s')
                                    );
            if(!$response){
                if($wpdb->last_error !== ''){
                    mytheme_print_error();
                }
            }else{
                mytheme_redirect();
            }
 }
```

And here is my function to show the error, also in functions.php:

```
function mytheme_print_error(){
        //append the error message after the form
        echo "<script>

                        var error = document.createElement('div');
                        error.class = 'error';
                        error.value = 'There was an error. Please try again';
                        var element = document.getElementById('create-team-submit');
                        element.appendChild(error);

                    </script>";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

I have double checked for typos but I can't seem to fix it. Any advice?

Comment: That is a JavaScript error, which happened most likely because the submit button wrapper (which has `create-team-submit` as its `id`) was not found on the page *when the `appendChild()` method is called*. Second issue I see, is that you should use `error.innerHTML` and *not* `error.value` since you're creating a `div` element and not a form field (e.g. `<input>`) that has a `value`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you. I changed `.value` to `.innerHTML`.

Comment: I am not sure what to do about the element not being found on the page - it should exist when the method is called because it's called after the form loads, right?

Comment: Yes.. but is the `mytheme_insert_new_team()` called *after* the form is displayed on the page, or is it *before* the content of the page loads? I'm asking because I could see that upon successful submission, the user is redirected (to the same page?).

Comment: If after the form is *submitted*, and there was an error, and the form hasn't been displayed yet, and you called the `mytheme_print_error()`, then that would result in the JS error there.